# Print list of files in a directory to a text file (but not the text file itself) from terminal

Tags: bash, ls

I would like to print all the filenames of every file in a directory to a `.txt` file.

Let's assume that I had a directory with 3 files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and I tried using `ls > output.txt`.

The thing is that when I open `output.txt` I find this list:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
output.txt
```

Is there a way to avoid printing the name of the file where I'm redirecting the output? Or better is there a command able to print all the filenames of files in a directory except one?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to print the output in the same directory as the other files?

Comment: @Jeremy It's just easier for me to work with it. But yes, I could create the file in another directory completely avoiding the problem. I didn't think about that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
printf '%s\n' * > output.txt
```

<sup>Note that this assumes that there's no preexisting `output.txt` file -
 if so, delete it first.</sup>

- `printf '%s\n' *` uses [globbing (filename expansion)](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) to robustly print the names of all files and subdirectories located in the current directory, line by line.
- Globbing happens *before* `output.txt` is created via output redirection `> output.txt` (which still happens before the command is *executed*, which explains your problem), so its name is *not* included in the output.
- Globbing also avoids the use of `ls`, whose use in scripting is [generally discouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

In general, it is not good to parse the output of `ls`, especially while writing production quality scripts that need to be in good standing for a long time.  See this page to find out why: [Don't parse ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

In your example, `output.txt` is a part of the output in `ls > output.txt` because shell arranges the redirection (to output.txt) before running `ls`.

The simplest way to get the right behavior for your case would be:

```
ls file*txt > output.txt # as long as you are looking for files named that way
```

or, store the output in a hidden file (or in a normal file in some other directory) and then move it to the final place:

```
ls > .output.txt && mv .output.txt output.txt
```

A more generic solution would be using `grep -v`:

```
ls | grep -vFx output.txt > output.txt
```

Or, you can use an array:

```
files=( "$(ls)" )
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" > output.txt
```

Comment: I think that still runs afoul of multiline filenames where one of the lines is `output.txt` (admittedly an exotic case). As for the other solution: Why not just use a string variable instead of a single-element array? `files="($ls)"; printf '%s' "$files" > output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

`ls` has an ignore option and we can use `find` command also.

- Using `ls` with ignore option

  ```
  ls -I "output.txt" > output.txt
  ls --ignore "output.txt" > output.txt
  ```

> `-I, --ignore` are same. This option says, as in the man page, do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN.

- Using `find`

  ```
  find \! -name "output.txt" > output.txt
  ```

> `-name` option in `find` finds files/directories whose name match the pattern.
>   `! -name` excludes whose name match the pattern.

```
    find \! -name "output.txt" -printf '%P\n' > output.txt
```

> %P strips the path and gives only names.

Comment: Your commands assume the use of _GNU_ utilities (Linux) - please make that prerequisite clear in your answer. For the `find` commands to be equivalent, you (a) need `-maxdepth 1` to prevent recursion, and (b) you must sort the list of filenames.

Comment: I don't have the ignore option on my machine. I'm not using Linux

Answer (score 1):

The most safe way, without assuming anything about the file names, is to use bash arrays (in memory) or a temporary file. A temporary file does not need memory, so it may be even safer. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(tempfile)
ls > $tmp
mv $tmp output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

My way would be like:

```
ls *.txt > output.txt
```

Note that shell will always expand all globs before running it. In your specific case, the glob expansion process goes like:

```
# "ls *.txt > output.txt" will be expanded as
ls file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > output.txt
```

The reason why you get "*output.txt*" in your final output file is that **redirection actually works among all connected programs** ***SIMULTANEOUSLY***.

That means the redirection process does not occur at the end of the program `ls`, but happens each time `ls` yields a line of output. In your case, when `ls` finishing yield the very first line, the file "output.txt" would be created, which will finally be return by `ls` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ls` and `awk` commands you can get the correct output.

```
ls -ltr | awk '/txt/ {print $9}' > output.txt
```

This will print only filenames.